# Unable to dynamically add products to cart using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cart

I am very new to Javascript and I'm building an ecommerce site, I am trying to add the image, name and price of an item and have it dynamically load in my cart.  I can't seem to get the scripting right to get this to function properly, and my code is slowly becoming a mess of failed attempts, lol. Please help, here is the code.

```
var cart = [];

function products () {
  var productTable = document.getElementById("productTable");
  for (var i in cart) {
       var row = productTable.itemRow(1);

      var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
      cell0.innerHTML = cart[i].image;
      cell1.innerHTML = cart[i].name;
      cell2.innerHTML = cart[i].price;
    };
  };
var addButton = document.getElementsByClassName("addToCart");
addButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
addToCart(itemImg, itemName, itemPrice) {
  for (var i in cart) {
    if (cart[i].name === itemName) {
        return;
    }
    this.image = itemImg
    this.name = itemName
    this.price = itemPrice
  };

  var itemImg = $(this.parentElement).find("img").attr('src');
  var itemName = $(this.parentElement).find("h3").text();
  var itemPrice = $(this.parentElement).find(".price").text();
  cart.push ({
    itemImg,
    itemName,
    itemPrice,
  });
};



<button class="addToCart">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: where is the onclick to call your addToCart function?

Comment: sorry about that, it was a bad copy and paste, I was copying relevant information and it got cut off.   Edited and added: var addButton = document.getElementsByClassName("addToCart");
  addButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  addToCart(itemImg, itemName, itemPrice) {